# Orthogonal diagonalization

Tags: diagonalization

Is there going to be a similarity in orthogonal diagonalization of these matrixes??

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    3 & 1 & \\
    1 & 3 & \\
    \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 3 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 1 & 3 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 3\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

I know that they both have one eigenvalue that that is the sum of the numbers in the row, and then eigenvalue 2 which has multiplicity (??? not sure how to translate it) 1 and 3.

And I also know that the eigenvectors for eigenvalue 4, 6 is going to be the same.

Comment: How can the eigenvectors be the same when they don’t even have the same dimension?

Comment: I meant similiar. It's going to be (1,1) for value 4 and (1,1,1,1) for value 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be two eigenspaces for such matrices. One is the span of $(1,1,\dots,1)$, which you can normalize to $\frac1{\sqrt n}(1,1,\dots,1)$, and the other is the orthogonal complement of this space. A basis for this space can be found by inspection: $$(1,-1,0,0,\dots,0) \\ (1,0,-1,0,\dots,0) \\ (1,0,0,-1,\dots,0) \\ \vdots \\ (1,0,0,0,\dots,-1).$$ If you then orthogonalize this basis via the Gram-Schmidt process, a pattern emerges: the $i$th basis vector is $${1\over\sqrt{(i+1)^2+i}}(1,\dots,1,-i,0,\dots),$$ with the initial run of $1$s having length $i$.

Applying this pattern to your examples, an orthogonal basis that diagonalizes the first matrix is $$\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,1) \\ \frac1{\sqrt2}(1,-1)$$ and for the second: $$\frac12(1,1,1,1) \\ \frac1{\sqrt2}(1,-1,0,0) \\ \frac1{\sqrt6}(1,1,-2,0) \\ \frac1{\sqrt{12}}(1,1,1,-3).$$

Of course, since one of the eigenspaces has dimension $n-1$, there are other orthonormal bases that will also diagonalize these matrices.